# Ring with special rules for add and mult

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

$R$ is a ring of integers with special rules for multiplication and addition.  Suppose that $f: \mathbb Z \to R$ is an isomorphism that is defined by $f(x) = x-2$.

1. What integer in the ring $R$ is zero?
2. What integer in the ring $R$ is the identity?
3. What are the units in $R$?
4. Find a formula for the special rule for addition.
5. Find a formula for the special rule for multiplication.

My thoughts: I know rules for the individual elements of the question.  My weakness lies with understanding the meaning of Rings and the question in general.  Is every element in the ring a product of the function x-2?

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism preserves the identity elements and units, so the zero in $R$ is $f(0)$ which is $-2$.  Questions 2 and 3 are similar.

Denote the addition in $R$ by $x\oplus y$.  By definition of isomorphism,
$$f(a)\oplus f(b)=f(a+b)\ .$$
If $x,y\in R$ are given then you can work out $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=f(a)$, $y=f(b)$, then simplify the preceding expression for $x\oplus y$.

Comment: So first question in this situation the zero is not necessarily the element that makes the equation zero but the value when zero is equal to x?

Comment: Zero is the element of the ring which gives no change when you "add" it to anything.

Comment: So the zero element would be zero... then the identity follows the a(identity)=a=(identity)a.  not sure about that and identifying if there are units

Comment: the only units in Z are 1 and -1 so would the units be the x's that give you 1 and -1 when you plug it into x-2 or is it just 1 and -1 alone?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1)You know that a ring isomorphism must take $0$ to $0$. So, $0$ in $R$ is just $f(0)$.

2) Does the ring isomorphism take $1$ to $1$? :)

3) Does the ring isomorphism take units to units?

4) $r_1+r_2=f(x)+f(y)$ where $x,y$ are the element in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x)=r_1, f(y)=r_2$